# how to create a relation between two tables in sql

Tags: sql

This is my first time using SQL, I tried to look in google but I didn't find my problem. I'm using this code from a course that I'm taking to create some tables, then I try to create the relation:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    addresss VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE payment_method
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    type_payment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
);

ALTER TABLE payment_method
    ADD customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    ADD remove_property INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE payment_method
    DROP COLUMN remove_property 

DESCRIBE payment_method;
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_store_product
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id);
```

but when I run it in SQL Workbench, I get these errors:

```
0   15  23:31:24    CREATE TABLE payment_method(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 type_payment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
 )  Error Code: 1050. Table 'payment_method' already exists 0.000 sec
0   16  23:31:54    CREATE TABLE payment_method(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 type_payment VARCHAR(50) NULL
 -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
 )  Error Code: 1050. Table 'payment_method' already exists 0.000 sec
0   17  23:32:14    CREATE TABLE payment_method(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 type_payment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
 )  Error Code: 1050. Table 'payment_method' already exists 0.000 sec
0   18  13:58:41    CREATE TABLE payment_method(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 type_payment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
 )  Error Code: 1050. Table 'payment_method' already exists 0.016 sec
0   19  13:58:44    CREATE TABLE payment_method(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 type_payment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 -- customer_id INT NOT NULL;
 )  Error Code: 1050. Table 'payment_method' already exists 0.000 sec
0   20  14:40:58    DESCRIBE peyment_method Error Code: 1146. Table 'store.peyment_method' doesn't exist    0.000 sec
```

Comment: you wrote "peyment_method" instead of "payment_method"

Comment: It clearly tells you the `payment_method` already exists. If you want create it again then drop it first and re-create. `drop table payment_method;` . Also check the spelling mistake as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Why are you creating the same table 5 times???

Comment: The error message is pretty clear "Table 'payment_method' already exists".  How else can we make it clearer?